# C#- Adding a new item to a collection<t>

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a collection that populates a treeview, and I want to add functionality that allows a node to be added with custom properties. Would the best way to go about it to clone the selected node and then edit the properties from there, or to add a completely new blank node?

The following method is how I'm currently trying to add nodes.

```
public void add()
    {
        hClass clone = new hClass();
        clone = SelectedNode;
        Topics.Add(clone);
    }
```

And then I call the method via a command.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you do with these nodes and which pieces of code an access them. Eric Lippert wrote a blog post focused on [immutable collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx) which might shed more light on your problem.

The collection is a set of references (pointers) to the nodes. If you assign an existing instance of `hClass` to the collection, a change to the instance will be visible in every place that can access it. If you're using it in a WPF GUI, read about [Responding to data source changes](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/)

Comment: Each node has properties which are then displayed in various textboxes/custom LaTeX displays to show each node's equation.